Background to Foreground - Toolbar vanishes - iPad only
iPad device only bug: When I open the app, I see the detail view tool bar fine. I open another app and come back to this app, the tool bar is not there. I select another item, tool bar appears. I select last item, tool bar appears. Now I added .id() to fix the bug where the tool bar was not reappearing at all, so now atleast it appears on tapping another list item. But still it's not a good experience to see tool bar vanished when coming back to the app. Can someone help please. It works very well in simulator but not in device.
   import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            // Leading side (typically a list or navigation links)
            List {
                NavigationLink("Item 1", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 1"))
                NavigationLink("Item 2", destination: detailView(text: "Detail View for Item 2"))
            }
        } detail: {
            // Default detail view when nothing is selected
            Text("Select an Item")
        }
    }
    
    // Function to generate a detail view with a principal toolbar item
    @ViewBuilder
    func detailView(text: String) -> some View {
        Text(text)
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    Text("Item Name \(text)")
                        .id(UUID())

                }
            }
    }
}

// Preview
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}


I can't reproduce your issue. Tested with Xcode 15.3 and a real iPhone 13 Pro running iOS 17.4.1. I ran a plain app with your ContentView. Selected an item, switched to another app, switched back. The title at the top was still there.

Sorry forgot to mention that this happens only in iPad
